# Accessing Images to show in Blade Outside the public folder in laravel

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have some images in storage/app/uploads which i want to show on front end. Let Say blade file. But we have acces to public folder only in laravel and images ar in storage folder as i mentioned above so how i couls acces it so i colud set the src='?' in image tag to see image.

Comment: `php artisan storage:link`

Comment: @thefallen could you explain a bit?

Comment: Create a symbolic link from "public/storage" to "storage/app/public" to access the files form storage directly.

Comment: and then use `asset()` helper to create url

Comment: in storage/app/uploads folder i have image a1.jpg how to access this using asset() if link is created successfully?